# Error when opening android application project

Tags: android, eclipse

When İ use my android application project, I get this error message. How can I fix this problem? I do not understand why it happens.
Please help me.

[I get this error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZuTZ.png)
[it is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNVfI.png)

Comment: Please show us the code where you get the error.

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported, please switch to Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: click "it is code."

Comment: It cannot resolve the support library, so it doesn't know what an ActionBarActivity is. Since it doesn't know that it extends an Activity, it doesn't think that it should have an onCreate().. etc

Comment: Did you download that version of Android support library already and compile it as a dependency in your build.gradle?